# Material UI components used with react-select resets scroll position

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-select

I am using `@material-ui/core - ^3.5.1`.

Have used `react-select` - ^2.2.0 in my code. Have customized `react-select` with material ui components.

My problem is scroll position is reset every time I open the drop-down.

Desired behaviour is it should scroll up to the position of selected element.
Example on [material-ui docs](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#react-select) site seems to be working fine, but when I open the given example link in codesandbox, it doesn't.

[Running example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-3s1w8), it's forked from original codesandbox example link given on material ui docs site (this example uses material-ui-4 and react-select 3 but has same issue).
Couldn't find any configurable prop for this behaviour in api docs.

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Does this problem occur when using the basic `Select` component or in conjunction with the `isMulti` prop?

Comment: Basic select component

Comment: Can you check if the selected option is inside the dropdown menu?

Comment: Yes it is inside it.

Comment: Seems like a regression from `2.4.4` to `3.0.0`. In version `2.4.4` it works as intended, but in version `3.0.0` and above it does not work at all. I would recommend to [file an issue](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/new) over at the `react-select` GitHub repository. Don´t forget to fill out the issue template correctly.

Comment: We have react-select 2.2 in our app and @material-ui/core 3.5.1. So not sure if its issue from react-select side.

Comment: Even with version `2.2.0` it works as expected. But the version of `material-ui` I tried was `4.0.2` because the sandbox you provided does not work with `3.5.1`.

Answer (score 1):

In you sandbox I changed react-select version to 2.4.4 and the scroll is restored.

In package.json use: `"react-select": "^2.4.4"`

Comment: In above sandbox, it works with react-select 2.2 as well. We are also using 2.2 in our app but it doesn't work. Maybe material-ui version issues.